# Is it possible to create a Nuget package for a non-dotnet DLL?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

Just a plain boring DLL, not created as a .Net project, which needs some sort of version control. Is it possible to create a Nuget package for this using the Nuget tools?

Comment: in what language this `DLL` is created ? C++ ? C ?

Comment: to answer your question : No you can't if that dll isn't written in any .Net language :)

Comment: Probably C++. it's not something we have written, and we don't have the source code and it's not available on Nuget in its own right. I just want to be sure that if/when a new version becomes available we don't suddenly hit a version conflict problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add any files as a content to a nuget package. It will be copied to the project output.

You can check out here: 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuspec#including-content-files

Example nuspec:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>PackageId</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Example</authors>
    <owners>Example</owners>
    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
   <contentFiles>
    <files include="any/any/yourdllfolder/**/*" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" />      
   </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Comment: That appears to require some .Net project in which you wish to pack some other file, is it not? That's not actually what I meant.

Comment: No you don't need any .net projects. You just copy your content files under the given path (any/any/yourdlllfolder). Then you can pack that with nuget.exe. And then you have your nupkg which you can push to any nuget server